# Emails from server going to junk/spam in Outlook and Gmail

Tags: email, spam, dovecot

Althought I have setup my rDNS correctly and have SPF and DomainKeys setup on my cPanel server I'm still getting all emails sent from our mailserver to spam, unless the domain is whitelisted by the receiver.

Any place I can go for them to whitelist my IP or how could I go about finding a solution?

Comment: There are lots of variables here. Is your IP on a blacklist (http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)? Is your content spammy? Has it been sending long enough to get a good reputation? Are you sending spikes of activity?

Comment: It is blacklisted in a like two blacklists and it's a recently setup server. There are no spikes of activity as it's just me and another user at the moment.

Comment: Blacklisted in two blacklists is going to give you deliverability issues. Work with the blacklists to get your server fixed/removed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if your server's IP is in a [blacklist](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)?